# Scrolling issues in reveal.js slides created by Jupyter nbconvert

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, reveal.js, nbconvert

I have an issue with Jupyter slides: when I create a presentation which exceeds the screen height, for example:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(5,10))
```

And then serve it with

```
jupyter nbconvert reveal.ipynb --to slides --post serve  --SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll=True
```

It works as expected: I can scroll down to see the entire plot.

However, when I host the created `reveal.slides.html` on my own server, where the latest `reveal.js` folder resides in the same folder as the `reveal.slides.html` file, then scrolling works as well, but after scrolling down, the page immediately snaps back to the top.

Does anyone else have this - how can I prevent this to keep the view where I scrolled to?

Comment: I think this might have to do with the optimization for mobile devices where swiping is used to change slides, but should not reposition the view, hence it snaps back to the top.